# Remove whitespace at top of sphinx pdflatex table of contents

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I'm building my python package documentation as HTML and as a latex PDF. The default latex pdf generated (manual class) has a large amount of white space at the top of the table of contents around the text "CONTENTS". I'm not super familiar with latex so when I've look at the generated `.tex` file I don't see anything that tells me how to remove the whitespace.

I've searched around and couldn't find a latex solution that worked. I also tried setting the `:caption:` on the toctree to an empty string, but that actually removes the entire TOC and all of my content.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image: whitespace example]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62125/how-to-remove-top-margin-above-tableofcontents for an answer

Comment: I found that and couldn't get it to work. I will try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of Sphinx for English language is to use Bjarne option to LaTeX package `fncychap` for chapter headings. But it also loads package `titlesec` for generally speaking title headings. It does not make a special chapter definition with `titlesec`, which simply gather the `fncychap` definition and wraps it in its own hooks. Anyway, making the story short we find

```
\ttl@save@mkschap #1->\vspace *{50\p@ }{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont \interlinepenalty \@M \DOTIS {#1} \vskip 40\p@ }
```

in a log trace and this is the `fncychap` definition of `\@makeschapterhead` as preserved by `titlesec` in its own macro `\ttl@save@mkschap`.

`fncychap` is loaded before `sphinx.sty`, there is no hook,

edit: *in fact the `'fncychap'` key whose default value is `'\\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}'` could serve to add some code to redefine the `fncychap` setting for un-numbered chapter titles. It is not that different from the approach with `'preamble'` key below, except that one would not have needed knowing about `titlesec` intervention in all this.*

but since recent Sphinx 1.5 you can use your own Jinja template for latex content. From the look of your `contents` which is small, I think you have an older version of Sphinx thus I will go for the LaTeX hacking variant something like this:

```
latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    'preamble': r"""
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@save@mkschap #1{\vspace *{10\p@ }{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \color{blue}%
    \normalfont \interlinepenalty \@M \DOTIS {#1} \vskip 10\p@ }}
\makeatother
""",

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
}
```

I have added a `\color{blue}` in there for demonstration purposes only, and modified the `\vspace`  and `\vskip` commands which is what you need.

The image shows however that there is some extra source of vertical space between Contents and the TOC contents (it remains even with `\vskip 0\p@` but one can do `\vskip -40\p@` ...), but I think you are after the top space above Contents and already using only `\vspace*{10pt}` reduced it a lot (not visible in screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: forgot to say that Sphinx removes spaces on top of *numbered*  chapter headings. But the TOC is done with a non-numbered chapter title, hence Sphinx does not change the initial vertical shift.

Comment: Awesome thanks. This worked great. I am using 1.4.9 at the moment, but if I was using 1.5 would I just add the preamble portion you gave inside a jinja template? I'm having trouble finding documentation on the jinja templating in sphinx.

Comment: Glad it worked... Jinja templating for LaTeX is briefly evoked at very end of [the latex docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/latex.html), and the used default template is to be found [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/stable/sphinx/templates/latex/content.tex_t). Immediately below `<%= fncychap %>` you could position `\def\@makeschapterhead#1{...same def as in my post...}`;  BTW, I have identified the source of extra space after title: it is in `fncychap`'s ``\DOTIS``, which is ``\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak\vskip 40\p@}`` in `fncychap.sty` for Bjarne.

Comment: When I evoked the template approach I had forgotten existence of `'fncychap'`'s key in `latex_elements` dictionary. It is probably preferable than the template approach. In conf.py, backslashes must be doubled if not using raw strings. In both I forgot to say you must have `\makeatletter... \makeatother` around LaTeX code.